# Vertical menu drop down color

Tags: css, wordpress

I asked a similar question earlier that was answered, but can't get this one to work. This is a different theme with a vertical menu down the side. When I hover over the menu, all sub menu's get the same color as the parent.

In the last question, I had to change this:

```
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester a:visited {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}
```

to this:

```
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:visited,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester > a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester > a:visited {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I tried that with this theme, but it didn't work. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Example

[image]

HTML

```
<nav class="site-nav">                  
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-has-children has-children menu-item-9"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/" aria-current="page">Home</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children has-children menu-item-6"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/sample-page/">Sample Page</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/test/">test</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/test-2/">test 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://url_address/testfolder/wordpresstestfolder/index.php/test-3/">test 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.site-nav a {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.site-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.site-nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.site-nav ul ul {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 100%;
    top: -2%
}

.site-nav ul li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.site-nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.site-nav li:hover ul ul {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 100%;
    top: -2%
}

.site-nav ul ul li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.site-nav ul li:hover ul ul ul {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 100%;
    top: -2%
}

.site-nav ul ul ul li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


.main-nav li.has-children > a:after {
 content: ' →';
 font-size: 15px;
 vertical-align: 0px;
}

.main-nav li li.has-children > a:after {
 content: ' →';
 font-size: 15px;
 vertical-align: 1px;
}

.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-menu-item > a:visited,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester > a:link,
.site-nav nav ul li.current-page_ancester > a:visited {
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
    background: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Just tried putting your code into a codepen, and it seems to be working fine? Only the hoverede menu gets the hover gray color: https://codepen.io/Djip/pen/NWPbmXw

Comment: what should it do? Because I see the sub menu's black text on white background. Looks fine

Comment: When I hover over Home, Sample Page pops up like it should, but it is black with white text. It should be white with black text unless it is the active page.

Comment: Ok, so this is a little weird. I copied the code into a plain html page and saved it, and it worked fine. That made me think it was something with Wordpress. I copied the theme into an older install and tried it, and it almost works correctly. The drop downs are showing with the correct background color, but the text is white for some reason. I'm going through the code to see if I can find where it is set to that, but no luck so far.